# Loop (array.from) on an HTMLCollection change item property

Tags: javascript, loops, htmlcollection

I'm trying to loop over an HTMLCollection (article tag), to dynamically add a css property "height"...

I have 9 articles in my block, with 9 different "offsetheight".

But, when I did a map on these articles, the offsetheights changed...

```
const shallow = Array.from(articles).map(article => article.offsetHeight) ;

console.log : Array(9) [ 362, 362, 362, 257, 257, 257, 446, 446, 446 ]
```

I don't understand why this happened. I'm working on a WordPress project with a 3 column Grid element (elementor), I think there is a link to this problem.....

Thanks!

Comment: You should add a sample of `articles` to the question so that we can debug the problem.

Comment: You could see if the same thing happens using […articles].map(). 
Sometimes javascript behaves differently if you save the result to a variable before doing your next step of processing i.e. const shallow = Array.from(articles); next line do the map